# How to do two captcha in a particular website in php?

Tags: jquery

I have written a code for checking the captcha if it is clicked or not on clicking the submit button. The code is given below :

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

 <script>

       $(document).ready(function(){

         $('#contact').click(function(e) {


            var v = grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha2);
            alert("okkkk!!!!!");
            if(v.length == 0)
         {
              alert("You can't leave Captcha Code empty");
              //return false;
              e.preventDefault();
         }



         });


       });


</script>

<script>

$(function() {

$('#send').on('click', function(ee) {

 var vv = grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha1);
 //alert(v);
if(vv.length == 0)
{
    alert("You can't leave Captcha Code empty");
    //return false;
    ee.preventDefault();
}

});

});

</script>
```

html code for captcha is :

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padd" id="recaptcha2"></div>

 <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padd" id="recaptcha1"></div>
```

But the script for checking if the captcha is clicked or not on submitting the button is not working now. Earlier it was working. Can anyone identify the error in this ?

Comment: Nobody here to help me out !!!

Comment: Do you see request in network tab? What does `grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha1)` and from where it's coming (not included library, only jQuery)? Do you see errors in console?

Comment: shouldn't google's recaptcha be validated in the server side?